# How to remove unwanted stylesheet from wp_head in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

In my twely.org website I have unwanted css in header. The unwanted CSS file is coming form wp_head. How can I remove the below stylesheets?

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='themify-shortcodes-css'  href='http://www.twely.org/wp-content/themes/elemin/themify/css/shortcodes.css?ver=1.5.8' type='text/css' media='all' />

<link rel='stylesheet' id='pretty-photo-css'  href='http://www.twely.org/wp-content/themes/elemin/themify/css/lightbox.css?ver=3.8' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using the wp_deregister_style() function:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_style

Answer (score 1):

Deregister/Dequeue styles is best practice

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_style
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style

But you can use this filter too, to filter out styles with string condition, or other conditions:

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', function($href){
if(strpos($href, "name-of-allowed.css") !== false) {
return $href;
}
return false;
});
```